# Capistrano bringing deleted git files to release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I am deploying with Capistrano and using git as my version control.

When I do cap deploy:update , it is bringing deleted files that are no longer in master to the /release/bla folder.

I do not wish to delete these files as I might need to check them in the future but also, I do not wish that Capistrano use them in my releases.

What are my options?

-- 
As per @LeeHambley's response below, I had a misunderstanding about how `git commit -a` works. git commit -a deletes the files from the current master but not their history. You can get their history as @LeeHambley details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like they should be added to your [`.gitignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) so that Git won't touch them, you could then easily upload them once by hand, or symlink them each deploy.

Typically, this would be done by uploading them into shared:

```
shared $ tree
.
└── config
   └── database.yml
   └── system
      └── uploads
```

And then people write tasks to symlink them into the release:

```
after 'deploy:symlink' do
  %w{database system}.each do |path|
    run "ln -s #{shared_path + path} #{latest_release + path}"
  end
end
```

This way, one would also add the following lines to gitignore:

```
/config/database.yml
/system/uploads
```

This would mean that they wouldn't be managed by Git anymore, each developer on your team would have their own copy of those files, and they'd have to be created on the server once by hand, then Git, or Capistrano won't mess with them again.

Regarding "I might need to check them in in the future" - I'd suggest you could commit `thefile.yaml.example` to the repository, and document the procedure for new installations to make your developer's lives easier.

When you add the files to the `.gitignore`, they'll also need to be deleted from the repository, this won't remove the history of the file, but it will remove it from the current head. If it's important you could always get the history of the file by doing `git log ./path/to/any/file/even/if/it/does/not/exist.anymore`. A wiser course of action might be to use `git mv` to move the file from it's existing position to `{oldname}.sample`, so the history will be transferred to the .sample file.